# Modifying JRE System Library

Tags: java, system

How do I modify the JRE System Library? Say to add a `isPrime()` method to the `java.security.SecureRandom` class

Comment: The most you could feasibly do in this instance is add a `isProbablePrime()` method anyway. I assume you're going to run some primality tests on the value, none of which are deterministic in most cases. However, it wouldn't even make sense to add it to the `SecureRandom` class as that encapsulates a random number *generator*, not a random number itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. Java is write once *run anywhere*. Relying on a hacked JRE will make your code non-portable. Just create a utility method where its required in the user code

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. Instead of you can extend that class and create your own custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the System JRE is not a good option.  All the System libraries loaded by the BootStrapClassloader which loads in secured manner. It will not allow the modified  system libraries to load as it might fails with some verification during class loading phase. Either check with some overridden method that could be used for the same where you can define your own behaviour.